# ADAL: Where do I view the resource ID's?

Tags: azure, active-directory, adal

I'm new to using `adal-node` npm package.

In the example it mentions:

```
var resource = '00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000';
```

Where is this ID from? From my use-case, I just want to batch update users in my AD.

Comment: @TonyJu, done. thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A resource is a service/app/api for which you ask an Identity provider like Azure AD to issue tokens for. You can also you the AppId (client Id) as a resource as well

'00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000' is the client Id of Azure AD Graph API (https://graph.windows.net/ ). This Api is being deprecated in favor of [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph) "https://graph.microsoft.com", which is the resource you should use.

Answer (score 3):

The value of the resource is a URI that identifies the resource for which the token is valid.

If you want to use Microsoft Graph API to [update your users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0) in your AD, you should use `https://graph.microsoft.com` for the resource.

You can refer to this [sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs/blob/dev/sample/windows-graph-sample.js). You will get the graph client to update the users.

```
const AuthenticationContext = require('adal-node').AuthenticationContext;
const MicrosoftGraph = require("@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client");

const authorityHostUrl = 'https://login.windows.net';
const tenantName = ''; //azure active directory tenant name. ie: name.onmicrosoft.com
const authorityUrl = authorityHostUrl + '/' + tenantName;
const applicationId = ''; //application id for registered app
const clientSecret = ''; //azure active directory registered app secret
const resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com"; //URI of resource where token is valid

const context = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUrl);

context.acquireTokenWithClientCredentials(
    resource,
    applicationId,
    clientSecret,
    function(err, tokenResponse) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('well that didn\'t work: ' + err.stack);
    } else {
      let client = MicrosoftGraph.Client.init({
        defaultVersion: 'v1.0',
        authProvider: (done) => {
            done(null, tokenResponse.accessToken);
        },
      });

      client
      .api('/users')
      .get((err, result) => {
          console.log(result, err);
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: I've selected Kalyan's answer as the accepted one because he also explains what the URI in my question was, which was part of the question for me. It's also concise and addressed my question exactly. The code you included is something that I already have and understand. I needed help primarily with understanding the resource parameter and its possible values.